# Hashing using SHA 256 and encrypting using AES

Tags: java, encryption, hash, aes

In order for me to consume a webservice, I need to generate a value for an header named `Authorization`. The steps to generate the header is as follows:

```
1. Hash Generation

   HashValue = SHA2(username, password, id)

2. Auth Key Generation

   Authkey = AES(Salt + anotherId + "=" + HashValue)
```

These are the algorithms details:

```
Algorithm - AES
Mode - ECB
Padding - PKCS5Padding
Secret key - someString
```

Now I will be performing the AES encryption using the above details and the secret key which is a string.

After the encryption, I will use the above generated encrypted value as a `header` in my rest service call.

I have done this so far:

```
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String id = "123456"; 

String toBeHashed = username + password + id;
MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] hashed = sha256.digest(toBeHashed.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String hashString = "=" + Base64.encodeBase64String(hashed);
System.out.println(hashString);

String salt = "salt";
String anotherId = "123";
byte[] forAuth = (salt + orgId + hashString).getBytes("UTF-8");

//Mocked "secret key". Original key string is of size 16 bytes.
byte[] secKey = "secret key".getBytes("UTF-8");

SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secKey, 0, secKey.length, "AES");

Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);

byte[] authorizationKey = aesCipher.doFinal(forAuth);

System.out.println("-------------------");
System.out.println("-------------------");
System.out.println(Base64.encodeBase64String(authorizationKey));
```

But still the backend service says that my authorization key is invalid. Please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: An AES key is 16, 24 or 32 bytes long, so your AES key is in principle invalid. Your provider might interpret such invalid key in another way than you expect.

Comment: Actually I have mocked the secret key here. When I try to convert the original key string to bytes and get the length, it is 16. So I think that is not the issue. I will edit this in the question.

Comment: It looks like inconsistent (A hash function has exactly one input and a block cipher has exactly 2 inputs) and incomplete (1. SHA-2? There are different lengths. 2. How is the encoding done?) web service documentation. Just ask them for example code or for a better documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **Encrypt and Decrypt using AES** 
    
    public static String encrypt(String value) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("randomStringVec".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("randomStringKey".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(1, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encrypted) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("randomStringVec".getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("randomStringKey".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(2, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    }


    **Encryption Using SHA256**
    private static String encrypt256(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        crypt.reset();
        crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new BigInteger(1, crypt.digest()).toString(16);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change this:

```
String hashString = "=" + Base64.encodeBase64String(hashed);
System.out.println(hashString);
```

To:

```
String hashString = "=" + new String(hashed);
System.out.println(hashString);
```

Since the hashed key is getting base64encoded before the authorization key generation.

Comment: `hashed` is a `byte[]` containing binary data. Never ever try to call `new String(byte[])` with non-string data!!!

Comment: Can you try this:

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
outputStream.write( (salt + orgId +"=").getByte());
outputStream.write( hashed );

byte forAuth[] = outputStream.toByteArray( );